# C++ Operator - method

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
struct Goods {
    int amount;
    int rarity;

    Goods operator -(const goods &other);
};
```

and this is how I attempt to implement operator- method:

```
Goods Goods::operator -(const Goods &other) {
    this->amount = amount - other.amount;
    this->rarity = rarity - other.rarity;
}
```

But this code doesn't work as intended. The actual value of this test

```
TEST(Mytest, GoodsMinus) {
    Goods g1{3, 4};
    Goods g2{2, 1};
    ASSERT_EQ(1, (g1 - g2).amount);
    ASSERT_EQ(3, (g1 - g2).rarity);
}
```

The actual value of first assert is 9435404, which is obviously wrong. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `operator-` return?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 3):

Your method isn't returning anything, and to add insult to injury, it's operating as a `-=`-like method, modifying the left-hand operand instead of returning a new `Good` while leaving the inputs untouched (if implemented as a method on the instance, which isn't the usual approach, it should be a `const` method).

I'm going to strongly recommend you read [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/364696), because even once you fix these issues, you're heading down the wrong path for writing maintainable, idiomatic code.

Answer (score 1):

Your operator - should return a new object which stores the new values calculated, in your case, as the difference of each member. In the code you provided you're (semantically) actually implementing the operator -=, in which, instead, you modify directly the data of the current object; you're in fact accessing this->... data and not a new object.

Therefore your - operator should look like:

```
Goods Goods::operator-(const Goods &other) const {
    Goods r;
    r.amount = amount - other.amount;
    r.rarity = rarity - other.rarity;

    return r;
}
```

EDIT:
As sugested I added const to the operator which means you can use it even with const object (which makes sense as you're not modifing the object internal state)